# Reversing Simple Javascript User Agent Logic

Tags: javascript, logic

Can someone help me reverse this logic?

```
if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) {}
```

I would like the statement to read as follows:
If user agent is NOT iPhone or NOT iPod

Right now I'm just leaving the first IF blank and using an ELSE, but I know there has to be a better solution.

Is there an opposite to .match?

Thanks!

Comment: When you say "not iPhone or not iPod" do you mean something that is neither an iPhone nor an iPod? It's going to be impossible for something to be both at the same time, but that statement makes it sound a little like you want a case where it is *either* not an iPod or not an iPhone. Your comment on the first answer implies you're looking for the former case (neither an iPhone nor an iPod).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if((!navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) && (!navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) {}
```

Comment: Just so I can learn... what exactly does prepending that exclamation point do? Does it reverse the statement?

Comment: Yes, it reverses the statement.

Comment: this should use || instead of && he wants OR

Comment: Yes - it's a negation or "not" operator.

Comment: @amosrivera- actually no, the true reversal of the statement would use an && operator.

Comment: i do agree on that, but hes not asking for traversing, he says: "I would like the statement to read as follows: If user agent is NOT iPhone **or** NOT iPod" take into account that if hes asking he probably does not understand the whole concept in conditions, i you should clarify.

Comment: I quote: "reverse this logic"

Answer (score 4):

Just for giggles, I'll add that there are two ways to do this due to the properties of [De Morgan's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

First, meaning "if it is not an iPhone and it is not an iPod" (as posted in the other answer):

```
if((!navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) && (!navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) {
    // Do something
}
```

And second, meaning "if it is not an iPhone or an iPod", which is just a logical negation of the entire current statement:

```
if(!(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) {
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this line here:

```
var isiOS = navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad)|(iPhone)|(iPod)/i) != null ? true : false;
```